# Simple Javascript Code it's not working in Windows Vista

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, windows-vista

I need help, I am having some headaches with this code.
The issue is that is not working in Google Chrome for Windows Vista. When i inspect element, what i see in the javascript console is the following error "Uncaught TypeError: items.forEach is not a function".

Here it is the code:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion a");

function toggleAccordion() {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
}

items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* ANIMATION*/

.container {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* ANIMATION*/


/* ANIMATION*/

.container2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* ANIMATION*/

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 48rem;
}

.container2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 48rem;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

.ocultar {}

@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .ocultar {
    display: none;
  }
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4d5974;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: #373d51;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion a.mas {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 1rem;
  color: #464748;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}

.accordion a.mas:hover,
.accordion a.mas:hover::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a.mas:hover::after {
  border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a.mas.active {
  color: #03b5d2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a.mas::after {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f218';
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #515c69;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #6f7479;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion a.mas.active::after {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f209';
  color: #03b5d2;
  border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion .content {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-height: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
}

.accordion .content p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.accordion .content.active {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2196F3">

  <title>Test page - FAQ</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css'>

  <!-- container for the img -->
  <style type="text/css">
    .contenedor_muestra {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .contenedor_muestra {
      margin-top: 19px;
      margin-bottom: 19px;
    }
    
    .contenedor_muestra img.muestra {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .espacio {
      margin-top: 80px;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End of container for the img -->

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <h2>Bla bla bla</h2>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Qué significa el ERROR 150 en los canales?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>El error 150 significa que el canal no se encuentra disponible en este momento. Si usted llega visualizar este ERROR por favor reporte el canal ahora mismo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¡No logro reproducir ningún canal!</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Tenga en cuenta que nuestro sitio web no tiene soporte para versiones inferiores de Windows 7, Android 5.0 (Lollipop) y IOS 8. <br>Para poder reproducir los canales en versiones inferiores de Android 5.0, puede descargar nuestra app oficial.
            <a href="#">Haga click aquí para instalar la app</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">Mi Smart TV no reproduce los canales</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Muchas Smarts TV nuevas traen un navegador desactualizado, es por esa la razón de porque no se puede reproducir los canales. Si usted tiene la posibilidad de instalar otro navegador o de actualizar el televisor, no lo dude en hacerlo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Qué navegadores recomiendan?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Nuestra recomendación es que siempre utilicen los navegadores Google Chrome y Firefox(Mozilla) en su última versión disponible.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Por qué aparece en negro la pantalla al reproducir los canales?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>La razón de que aparezca la pantalla en negro es debido a la velocidad de internet que usted tiene. Los canales que tienen una mayor calidad de imagen (4K, Full HD, 1080p, 720p), requieren de una mayor velocidad de internet(Mínimo 35Mbs). </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuál es la velocidad de internet mínima que necesito tener?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>La velocidad de internet recomendada para reproducir canales en SD(<i>Calidad estandar 360p a 480p</i>) es de 10Mbs, canales con calidad de imagen HD <i>(720p)</i> 15Mbs, Full HD (<i>1080p</i>) 25mbs, 4k 35Mbs. Si desea saber la velocidad de
            su internet, <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>. Aconsejamos a nuestros usuarios:
          </p>
          <p>_ Tener fibra óptica en su hogar para una mejor experiencia en reproducción.
            <br> _ Conectar el dispositivo que está reproduciendo los canales con el cable Ethernet, <i>(El cable Ethernet es el que va conectado
        al router o modem a su dispositivo)</i>.
            <br> _ No tener muchos dispositivos conectados simultáneamente ya que la banda ancha se divide para cada dispositivo. Ejemplo:
            <i>si tienes contratado 10Mbs de internet y dos dispositivos conectados, tendrás 5Mb para cada dispositivo. Tenga en cuenta que
        necesita 10Mbs para poder reproducir cualquier canal</i>.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo instalo la app gratuita en ANDROID?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para instalar nuestra app gratuita tiene dos formas diferentes:<br></p>
          <p>_ La primera opción, es ir a la tienda de apps (Play Store) en su dispositivo, buscar nuestra app llamada "..." y luego instalarla.</p>
          <p>_ La segunda opción, es descargar la app desde nuestra página <a href="#">haga click aquí
        para descargar la app.</a> Una vez se haya descargado, lo siguiente que tendremos que hacer es instalarlo en nuestro dispositivo. Antes de comenzar, deberá habilitar el sistema para que acepte la instalación de aplicaciones que no vengan desde
            Google Play.</p>
          <p>Para ello, hay que dirigirse a <i>Ajustes->Seguridad</i>. En este submenú aparecerá una opción llamada <i>"Orígenes desconocidos"</i>, la cual tendrá que activar. En el momento que vaya a activarlo, en la pantalla aparecerá una advertencia para
            re confirmar, tendrá que aceptar. Luego una vez ya activada la opción, podrá instalar nuestra app.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="#">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¡Ahora en dispositivos IOS puedes usar nuestra app gratuita!</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para añadir nuestra app en su dispositivo IOS, siga estos pasos:</p>
          <p>_ Entre a nuestro sitio web utilizando el navegador <i>Safari</i> <br> _ Presione el botón de compartir igual al que se muestra en imagen, luego apareceran varias opciones, elija la opción que dice:
            <i>"Agregar a inicio"</i>.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="#">
          </div>
          <p>Luego de haber presionado el botón, nos saldra un cuadro para modificar el nombre de la app y poder guardarla. Una vez ya guardada, iremos a inicio y nos aparecerá la aplicación. Y listo, a disfrutar.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="#">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo reproducir los canales en el ChromeCast?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Estos pasos son los mismos para dispositivos Android y IOS(Apple):</p>
          <p>_ Abra la aplicación<i>"Google Home"</i>. Si no la tiene instalada, por favor instálala en la tienda de aplicaciones de su dispositivo.
          </p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="#">
          </div>
          <p>Una vez ya abierta la aplicación, presionará la hamburguesa que se encuentra en la parte superior, luego de haberla presionado saldrá un menú con varias opciones, usted tendrá que elegir la primera opción <i>"Enviar pantalla o audio"</i>.
            <br>Se abrirá la pestaña "Enviar pantalla o audio", para empezar a enviar contenido a su ChromeCast solo hace falta presionar presionar el botón azul, seleccionar el dispositivo ChromeCast y listo. Los pasos son siempre los mismos para conectarse
            con el dispositivo.
          </p>
          <p></p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="#">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="espacio">
    </div>

    <!-- OCULTAR -->
    <!-- OCULTAR -->
    <div class="ocultar">
      <hr>
      <h2>Bla Bla Bla 2</h2>
      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cómo puedo pedir una demo?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Las demos se piden por Facebook, si desea probar una demostración de nuestro servicio
              <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cuántos canales tienen?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Contamos con 5000 señales, <i>(canales, estrenos de peliculas  y series)</i>, todos los meses agregamos más señales
              <a href="#">haga click aquí para ver la lista completa</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cuánto cuesta?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Tenemos varios paquetes con tiempos de experación diferentes, si desea ver los precios
              <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Multiplataforma?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Así es... Nuestro servicio privado igual como el gratuito es multiplataforma, eso significa que podrás reproducir los canales en cualquier dispositivo que funcione con internet. Ejemplo: <i>Windows, Linux, Apple, SmartTV, Android, TV BOX, Mag, Enigma2, Xbox,
        Roku, Kodi, Rosadin y mucho más</i>. Si desea saber como reproducir los canales en cualquiera de esas plataformas, contáctenos
              <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿El servicio es estable?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Contamos con la mejor infraestructura para así poder ofrecer el servicio más estable del mercado, de esta forma garantizamos la calidad y servicio a nuestros clientes..
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cómo instalo la app privada en ANDROID?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Para instalar nuestra app privada siga estos pasos:<br></p>
            <p>Descargue la app desde nuestra página <a href="#">haga click aquí
    para descargar la app.</a> Una vez se haya descargado, lo siguiente que tendremos que hacer es instalarlo en nuestro dispositivo. Antes de comenzar, deberá habilitar el sistema para que acepte la instalación de aplicaciones que no vengan desde Google
              Play.
            </p>
            <p>Para ello, hay que dirigirse a <i>Ajustes->Seguridad</i>. En este submenú aparecerá una opción llamada <i>"Orígenes desconocidos"</i>, la cual tendrá que activar. En el momento que vaya a activarlo, en la pantalla aparecerá una advertencia
              para re confirmar, tendrá que aceptar. Luego una vez ya activada la opción, podrá instalar nuestra app.</p>
            <div class="contenedor_muestra">
              <img class="muestra" src="#">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cuál es la velocidad de internet mínima que necesito tener?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>La velocidad de internet recomendada para reproducir canales en SD(<i>Calidad estandar 360p a 480p</i>) es de 10Mbs, canales con calidad de imagen HD <i>(720p)</i> 15Mbs, Full HD (<i>1080p</i>) 25mbs, 4k 35Mbs. Si desea saber la velocidad
              de su internet, <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>. Aconsejamos a nuestros usuarios:
            </p>
            <p>_ Tener fibra óptica en su hogar para una mejor experiencia en reproducción.
              <br> _ Conectar el dispositivo que está reproduciendo los canales con el cable Ethernet, <i>(El cable Ethernet es el que va conectado
    al router o modem a su dispositivo)</i>.
              <br> _ No tener muchos dispositivos conectados simultáneamente ya que la banda ancha se divide para cada dispositivo. Ejemplo:
              <i>si tienes contratado 10Mbs de internet y dos dispositivos conectados, tendrás 5Mb para cada dispositivo. Tenga en cuenta que
    necesita 10Mbs para poder reproducir cualquier canal</i>.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">Formas de pago</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Para su comodidad y seguridad, aceptamos pagos únicamente a través de Paypal. Si no posee una cuenta de Paypal no se preocupe, ahora también se puede realizar pagos a través de esta plataforma sin tener una cuenta. Por más información, no
              dude en contactarnos.
              <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- CONTENEDOR 2 -->
  <!-- CONTENEDOR 2-->
  <div class="container2">
    <h2>Preguntas Frecuentes - Sección IPTV Privado</h2>
    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo puedo pedir una demo?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Las demos se piden por Facebook, si desea probar una demostración de nuestro servicio
            <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuántos canales tienen?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Contamos con 5000 señales, <i>(canales, estrenos de peliculas  y series)</i>, todos los meses agregamos más señales
            <a href="#">haga click aquí para ver la lista completa</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuánto cuesta?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Tenemos varios paquetes con tiempos de experación diferentes, si desea ver los precios
            <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Multiplataforma?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Así es... Nuestro servicio privado igual como el gratuito es multiplataforma, eso significa que podrás reproducir los canales en cualquier dispositivo que funcione con internet. Ejemplo: <i>Windows, Linux, Apple, SmartTV, Android, TV BOX, Mag, Enigma2, Xbox,
        Roku, Kodi, Rosadin y mucho más</i>. Si desea saber como reproducir los canales en cualquiera de esas plataformas, contáctenos
            <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿El servicio es estable?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Contamos con la mejor infraestructura para así poder ofrecer el servicio más estable del mercado, de esta forma garantizamos la calidad y servicio a nuestros clientes..
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo instalo la app en ANDROID?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para instalar nuestra app privada siga estos pasos:<br></p>
          <p>Descargue la app desde nuestra página <a href="#">haga click aquí
    para descargar la app.</a> Una vez se haya descargado, lo siguiente que tendremos que hacer es instalarlo en nuestro dispositivo. Antes de comenzar, deberá habilitar el sistema para que acepte la instalación de aplicaciones que no vengan desde Google
            Play.
          </p>
          <p>Para ello, hay que dirigirse a <i>Ajustes->Seguridad</i>. En este submenú aparecerá una opción llamada <i>"Orígenes desconocidos"</i>, la cual tendrá que activar. En el momento que vaya a activarlo, en la pantalla aparecerá una advertencia para
            re confirmar, tendrá que aceptar. Luego una vez ya activada la opción, podrá instalar nuestra app.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="#">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuál es la velocidad de internet mínima que necesito tener?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>La velocidad de internet recomendada para reproducir canales en SD(<i>Calidad estandar 360p a 480p</i>) es de 10Mbs, canales con calidad de imagen HD <i>(720p)</i> 15Mbs, Full HD (<i>1080p</i>) 25mbs, 4k 35Mbs. Si desea saber la velocidad de
            su internet, <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>. Aconsejamos a nuestros usuarios:
          </p>
          <p>_ Tener fibra óptica en su hogar para una mejor experiencia en reproducción.
            <br> _ Conectar el dispositivo que está reproduciendo los canales con el cable Ethernet, <i>(El cable Ethernet es el que va conectado
    al router o modem a su dispositivo)</i>.
            <br> _ No tener muchos dispositivos conectados simultáneamente ya que la banda ancha se divide para cada dispositivo. Ejemplo:
            <i>si tienes contratado 10Mbs de internet y dos dispositivos conectados, tendrás 5Mb para cada dispositivo. Tenga en cuenta que
    necesita 10Mbs para poder reproducir cualquier canal</i>.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">Formas de pago</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para su comodidad y seguridad, aceptamos pagos únicamente a través de Paypal. Si no posee una cuenta de Paypal no se preocupe, ahora también se puede realizar pagos a través de esta plataforma sin tener una cuenta. Por más información, no dude
            en contactarnos.
            <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I would be greateful, if anyone can help me.
Thanks...

Comment: result of querySelectorAll doesn't have a forEach method in the **old** version of Chrome you must be running - try upgrading chrome

Comment: if you cant' upgrade chrome for some insane reason ... you can always do `Array.from(items).forEach(item => ....`

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX The last version of Chrome for Vista is 50, `NodeList.forEach` was added in 51 -- he just missed it. Luckily, `Array.from` was added in 45.

Comment: However, `Array.from()` won't work in any version of IE.

Comment: There are polyfills for all of these in the MDN documentation.

Comment: the question seems to be about an old version of Chrome ... plus there's `=>` in the code - so internet explorer isn't even in the equation :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you get rid of `.forEach` (or any other loop) and add the event listener directly to `.accordion`. Seems it simplifies your code:

```js
document
  .querySelector(".accordion")
    .addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion);

function toggleAccordion(e) {
  var a = e.target;
  if (a.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') return true;
  a.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* ANIMATION*/

.container {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* ANIMATION*/


/* ANIMATION*/

.container2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* ANIMATION*/

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 48rem;
}

.container2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4rem;
  width: 48rem;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .container2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

.ocultar {}

@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .ocultar {
    display: none;
  }
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4d5974;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: #373d51;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion a.mas {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 3rem 1rem 1rem;
  color: #464748;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
}

.accordion a.mas:hover,
.accordion a.mas:hover::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a.mas:hover::after {
  border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion .active a.mas {
  color: #03b5d2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion a.mas::after {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f218';
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #515c69;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #6f7479;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion .active a.mas::after {
  font-family: 'Ionicons';
  content: '\f209';
  color: #03b5d2;
  border: 1px solid #03b5d2;
}

.accordion .content {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  max-height: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0.15s;
}

.accordion .content p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.accordion .active .content {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.35s ease 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#2196F3">

  <title>Test page - FAQ</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css'>

  <!-- container for the img -->
  <style type="text/css">
    .contenedor_muestra {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .contenedor_muestra {
      margin-top: 19px;
      margin-bottom: 19px;
    }
    
    .contenedor_muestra img.muestra {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .espacio {
      margin-top: 80px;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End of container for the img -->

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <h2>Bla bla bla</h2>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Qué significa el ERROR 150 en los canales?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>El error 150 significa que el canal no se encuentra disponible en este momento. Si usted llega visualizar este ERROR por favor reporte el canal ahora mismo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¡No logro reproducir ningún canal!</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Tenga en cuenta que nuestro sitio web no tiene soporte para versiones inferiores de Windows 7, Android 5.0 (Lollipop) y IOS 8. <br>Para poder reproducir los canales en versiones inferiores de Android 5.0, puede descargar nuestra app oficial.
            <a href="#">Haga click aquí para instalar la app</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">Mi Smart TV no reproduce los canales</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Muchas Smarts TV nuevas traen un navegador desactualizado, es por esa la razón de porque no se puede reproducir los canales. Si usted tiene la posibilidad de instalar otro navegador o de actualizar el televisor, no lo dude en hacerlo.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Qué navegadores recomiendan?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Nuestra recomendación es que siempre utilicen los navegadores Google Chrome y Firefox(Mozilla) en su última versión disponible.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Por qué aparece en negro la pantalla al reproducir los canales?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>La razón de que aparezca la pantalla en negro es debido a la velocidad de internet que usted tiene. Los canales que tienen una mayor calidad de imagen (4K, Full HD, 1080p, 720p), requieren de una mayor velocidad de internet(Mínimo 35Mbs). </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuál es la velocidad de internet mínima que necesito tener?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>La velocidad de internet recomendada para reproducir canales en SD(<i>Calidad estandar 360p a 480p</i>) es de 10Mbs, canales con calidad de imagen HD <i>(720p)</i> 15Mbs, Full HD (<i>1080p</i>) 25mbs, 4k 35Mbs. Si desea saber la velocidad de
            su internet, <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>. Aconsejamos a nuestros usuarios:
          </p>
          <p>_ Tener fibra óptica en su hogar para una mejor experiencia en reproducción.
            <br> _ Conectar el dispositivo que está reproduciendo los canales con el cable Ethernet, <i>(El cable Ethernet es el que va conectado
        al router o modem a su dispositivo)</i>.
            <br> _ No tener muchos dispositivos conectados simultáneamente ya que la banda ancha se divide para cada dispositivo. Ejemplo:
            <i>si tienes contratado 10Mbs de internet y dos dispositivos conectados, tendrás 5Mb para cada dispositivo. Tenga en cuenta que
        necesita 10Mbs para poder reproducir cualquier canal</i>.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo instalo la app gratuita en ANDROID?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para instalar nuestra app gratuita tiene dos formas diferentes:<br></p>
          <p>_ La primera opción, es ir a la tienda de apps (Play Store) en su dispositivo, buscar nuestra app llamada "..." y luego instalarla.</p>
          <p>_ La segunda opción, es descargar la app desde nuestra página <a href="#">haga click aquí
        para descargar la app.</a> Una vez se haya descargado, lo siguiente que tendremos que hacer es instalarlo en nuestro dispositivo. Antes de comenzar, deberá habilitar el sistema para que acepte la instalación de aplicaciones que no vengan desde
            Google Play.</p>
          <p>Para ello, hay que dirigirse a <i>Ajustes->Seguridad</i>. En este submenú aparecerá una opción llamada <i>"Orígenes desconocidos"</i>, la cual tendrá que activar. En el momento que vaya a activarlo, en la pantalla aparecerá una advertencia para
            re confirmar, tendrá que aceptar. Luego una vez ya activada la opción, podrá instalar nuestra app.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="http://www.dazplayer.com/faq/img/app_ins_origendesconocido.jpg?536" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¡Ahora en dispositivos IOS puedes usar nuestra app gratuita!</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para añadir nuestra app en su dispositivo IOS, siga estos pasos:</p>
          <p>_ Entre a nuestro sitio web www.dazplayer.com utilizando el navegador <i>Safari</i> <br> _ Presione el botón de compartir igual al que se muestra en imagen, luego apareceran varias opciones, elija la opción que dice:
            <i>"Agregar a inicio"</i>.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="http://www.dazplayer.com/faq/img/app_iphone1.jpg?4116" alt="">
          </div>
          <p>Luego de haber presionado el botón, nos saldra un cuadro para modificar el nombre de la app y poder guardarla. Una vez ya guardada, iremos a inicio y nos aparecerá la aplicación. Y listo, a disfrutar.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="http://www.dazplayer.com/faq/img/app_iphone2.jpg?8130" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo reproducir los canales en el ChromeCast?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Estos pasos son los mismos para dispositivos Android y IOS(Apple):</p>
          <p>_ Abra la aplicación<i>"Google Home"</i>. Si no la tiene instalada, por favor instálala en la tienda de aplicaciones de su dispositivo.
          </p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="http://www.dazplayer.com/faq/img/goo_home.jpg?255" alt="">
          </div>
          <p>Una vez ya abierta la aplicación, presionará la hamburguesa que se encuentra en la parte superior, luego de haberla presionado saldrá un menú con varias opciones, usted tendrá que elegir la primera opción <i>"Enviar pantalla o audio"</i>.
            <br>Se abrirá la pestaña "Enviar pantalla o audio", para empezar a enviar contenido a su ChromeCast solo hace falta presionar presionar el botón azul, seleccionar el dispositivo ChromeCast y listo. Los pasos son siempre los mismos para conectarse
            con el dispositivo.
          </p>
          <p></p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="http://www.dazplayer.com/faq/img/goo_home2.jpg?3073" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="espacio">
    </div>

    <!-- OCULTAR -->
    <!-- OCULTAR -->
    <div class="ocultar">
      <hr>
      <h2>Bla Bla Bla 2</h2>
      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cómo puedo pedir una demo?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Las demos se piden por Facebook, si desea probar una demostración de nuestro servicio
              <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cuántos canales tienen?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Contamos con 5000 señales, <i>(canales, estrenos de peliculas  y series)</i>, todos los meses agregamos más señales
              <a href="#">haga click aquí para ver la lista completa</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cuánto cuesta?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Tenemos varios paquetes con tiempos de experación diferentes, si desea ver los precios
              <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Multiplataforma?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Así es... Nuestro servicio privado igual como el gratuito es multiplataforma, eso significa que podrás reproducir los canales en cualquier dispositivo que funcione con internet. Ejemplo: <i>Windows, Linux, Apple, SmartTV, Android, TV BOX, Mag, Enigma2, Xbox,
        Roku, Kodi, Rosadin y mucho más</i>. Si desea saber como reproducir los canales en cualquiera de esas plataformas, contáctenos
              <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿El servicio es estable?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Contamos con la mejor infraestructura para así poder ofrecer el servicio más estable del mercado, de esta forma garantizamos la calidad y servicio a nuestros clientes..
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cómo instalo la app privada en ANDROID?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Para instalar nuestra app privada siga estos pasos:<br></p>
            <p>Descargue la app desde nuestra página <a href="#">haga click aquí
    para descargar la app.</a> Una vez se haya descargado, lo siguiente que tendremos que hacer es instalarlo en nuestro dispositivo. Antes de comenzar, deberá habilitar el sistema para que acepte la instalación de aplicaciones que no vengan desde Google
              Play.
            </p>
            <p>Para ello, hay que dirigirse a <i>Ajustes->Seguridad</i>. En este submenú aparecerá una opción llamada <i>"Orígenes desconocidos"</i>, la cual tendrá que activar. En el momento que vaya a activarlo, en la pantalla aparecerá una advertencia
              para re confirmar, tendrá que aceptar. Luego una vez ya activada la opción, podrá instalar nuestra app.</p>
            <div class="contenedor_muestra">
              <img class="muestra" src="http://www.dazplayer.com/faq/img/app_ins_origendesconocido.jpg?2202" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">¿Cuál es la velocidad de internet mínima que necesito tener?</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>La velocidad de internet recomendada para reproducir canales en SD(<i>Calidad estandar 360p a 480p</i>) es de 10Mbs, canales con calidad de imagen HD <i>(720p)</i> 15Mbs, Full HD (<i>1080p</i>) 25mbs, 4k 35Mbs. Si desea saber la velocidad
              de su internet, <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>. Aconsejamos a nuestros usuarios:
            </p>
            <p>_ Tener fibra óptica en su hogar para una mejor experiencia en reproducción.
              <br> _ Conectar el dispositivo que está reproduciendo los canales con el cable Ethernet, <i>(El cable Ethernet es el que va conectado
    al router o modem a su dispositivo)</i>.
              <br> _ No tener muchos dispositivos conectados simultáneamente ya que la banda ancha se divide para cada dispositivo. Ejemplo:
              <i>si tienes contratado 10Mbs de internet y dos dispositivos conectados, tendrás 5Mb para cada dispositivo. Tenga en cuenta que
    necesita 10Mbs para poder reproducir cualquier canal</i>.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <a class="mas">Formas de pago</a>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Para su comodidad y seguridad, aceptamos pagos únicamente a través de Paypal. Si no posee una cuenta de Paypal no se preocupe, ahora también se puede realizar pagos a través de esta plataforma sin tener una cuenta. Por más información, no
              dude en contactarnos.
              <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- CONTENEDOR 2 -->
  <!-- CONTENEDOR 2-->
  <div class="container2">
    <h2>Preguntas Frecuentes - Sección IPTV Privado</h2>
    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo puedo pedir una demo?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Las demos se piden por Facebook, si desea probar una demostración de nuestro servicio
            <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuántos canales tienen?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Contamos con 5000 señales, <i>(canales, estrenos de peliculas  y series)</i>, todos los meses agregamos más señales
            <a href="#">haga click aquí para ver la lista completa</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuánto cuesta?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Tenemos varios paquetes con tiempos de experación diferentes, si desea ver los precios
            <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Multiplataforma?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Así es... Nuestro servicio privado igual como el gratuito es multiplataforma, eso significa que podrás reproducir los canales en cualquier dispositivo que funcione con internet. Ejemplo: <i>Windows, Linux, Apple, SmartTV, Android, TV BOX, Mag, Enigma2, Xbox,
        Roku, Kodi, Rosadin y mucho más</i>. Si desea saber como reproducir los canales en cualquiera de esas plataformas, contáctenos
            <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿El servicio es estable?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Contamos con la mejor infraestructura para así poder ofrecer el servicio más estable del mercado, de esta forma garantizamos la calidad y servicio a nuestros clientes..
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cómo instalo la app en ANDROID?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para instalar nuestra app privada siga estos pasos:<br></p>
          <p>Descargue la app desde nuestra página <a href="#">haga click aquí
    para descargar la app.</a> Una vez se haya descargado, lo siguiente que tendremos que hacer es instalarlo en nuestro dispositivo. Antes de comenzar, deberá habilitar el sistema para que acepte la instalación de aplicaciones que no vengan desde Google
            Play.
          </p>
          <p>Para ello, hay que dirigirse a <i>Ajustes->Seguridad</i>. En este submenú aparecerá una opción llamada <i>"Orígenes desconocidos"</i>, la cual tendrá que activar. En el momento que vaya a activarlo, en la pantalla aparecerá una advertencia para
            re confirmar, tendrá que aceptar. Luego una vez ya activada la opción, podrá instalar nuestra app.</p>
          <div class="contenedor_muestra">
            <img class="muestra" src="http://www.dazplayer.com/faq/img/app_ins_origendesconocido.jpg?9910" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">¿Cuál es la velocidad de internet mínima que necesito tener?</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>La velocidad de internet recomendada para reproducir canales en SD(<i>Calidad estandar 360p a 480p</i>) es de 10Mbs, canales con calidad de imagen HD <i>(720p)</i> 15Mbs, Full HD (<i>1080p</i>) 25mbs, 4k 35Mbs. Si desea saber la velocidad de
            su internet, <a href="#">haga click aquí</a>. Aconsejamos a nuestros usuarios:
          </p>
          <p>_ Tener fibra óptica en su hogar para una mejor experiencia en reproducción.
            <br> _ Conectar el dispositivo que está reproduciendo los canales con el cable Ethernet, <i>(El cable Ethernet es el que va conectado
    al router o modem a su dispositivo)</i>.
            <br> _ No tener muchos dispositivos conectados simultáneamente ya que la banda ancha se divide para cada dispositivo. Ejemplo:
            <i>si tienes contratado 10Mbs de internet y dos dispositivos conectados, tendrás 5Mb para cada dispositivo. Tenga en cuenta que
    necesita 10Mbs para poder reproducir cualquier canal</i>.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <a class="mas">Formas de pago</a>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Para su comodidad y seguridad, aceptamos pagos únicamente a través de Paypal. Si no posee una cuenta de Paypal no se preocupe, ahora también se puede realizar pagos a través de esta plataforma sin tener una cuenta. Por más información, no dude
            en contactarnos.
            <a href="#">haga click aquí para contactarnos</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- Dessaparece a una cierta px -->
  <!-- Dessaparece a una cierta px -->

  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```